# Java reading file and storing text as array

Tags: java, arrays, storing-data

I wrote a program someone told me to do for reading file and storing the text as an array, but when I run the program, I get an error that looks like this:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: KeyWestTemp.txt (No such file                or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:656)
at HeatIndex.main(HeatIndex.java:32)
```

Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

I want to have my program display the array to make sure it works correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the program code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class HeatIndex {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    // TODO code application logic here

    // // read KeyWestTemp.txt

    // create token1
    String token1 = "";

    // create Scanner inFile1
    Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File("KeyWestTemp.txt")).useDelimiter(",\\s*");

    // create List
    List<String> temps = new LinkedList<String>();

    // while loop
    while(inFile1.hasNext()){

        // find next line
        token1 = inFile1.next();

        // initialize temps
        temps.add(token1);
    }

    // close inFile1
    inFile1.close();

    // create array
    String[] tempsArray = temps.toArray(new String[0]);

    // for-each loop
    for(String s : tempsArray){

        // display s to make sure program works correctly
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Check your file name... the exception says there is no file under the name you put

Comment: Don't forget to mark the response that helped you the most as 'answer'. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your program is unable to locate your file. Make sure the file is in your working directory, or change `new File("KeyWestTemp.txt")` to provide a complete path (e.g. C:/Users/...../KeyWestTemp.txt).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the file `KeyWestTemp.txt` is not found by the Java program. The most likely problem is that you haven't placed it in the right place.

You have 2 options:

1. Place the file in the working directory, from where you run the `java` command
2. When initializing the Scanner, set the full path: `new Scanner(new File("/file/path/to/KeyWestTemp.txt"))` to the file

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to fix it:

1. Put your txt file in the same dir of your Java program.
2. Write the full path of the txt file (c:/files...). Remember to use File.separator instead of the "/" or "\" to make the program platform independent.